# Scratch Org missing from Salesforce DX org list

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I'm trying to set up a Heroku Pipeline for Salesforce DX as described in this example: https://github.com/wadewegner/salesforce-dx-pipeline-mdapi-sample.

The process works fine up until a pull request is created and the review app is created (Heroku runs a script which authenticates to my Dev Hub, creates a new Scratch org, and pushes the branch to it)

The Heroku log shows that the Scratch Org has been created:

```
Successfully created scratch org: 00D3D0000000o2bUAA, username: test-tjcuvjdzxnig@example.com
```

The Scratch org is also visible in my Dev Hub UI:
[image]

However, the Scratch Org is never listed when running the Salesforce DX CLI **sfdx force:org:list** command. The command will list all other orgs I've authenticated in the CLI, as well as Scratch Orgs created directly in the CLI, but never Scratch Orgs created from Heroku. Likewise the **sfdx force:org:open** command also fails with the new scratch org username:

```
sfdx force:org:open -u test-tjcuvjdzxnig@example.com
ERROR: No org configuration found for name test-tjcuvjdzxnig@example.com.
```

Consequently, I cannot actually log into the review app Scratch Org. Have I overlooked something here? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not overlooking anything but you are not understanding few concepts on how authentication works between CLI and Salesforce.

The machine that creates the scratch can log into that using sfdx force:org:open .Since you never created the org from your local machine this wont show up .

Here is what you can do if you want to log into the scratch org .First reset the password or create another user in your scratch org that you have password with .

Then run the login command as below to authenticate and set alias once login

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias myScratchOrg
```

On successful auth set as default as below

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=myScratchOrg
```

Now open it using `sfdx force:org:open -u myScratchOrg`